# Audit with SubSonic

Tags: subsonic

Does some resource of Audit exist in SubSonic?

Answer (score 1):

It has the built in CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedOn, and ModifiedBy columns that you would just need to add to your table.  For further audit capabilities I would suggest writing triggers.

Comment: No, please don't write triggers. They're a HUGE pain to maintain.

Comment: They are?  Just for auditing?  I've actually never really had an issue there, and thought that having that sort of functionality embedded in the db itself improved perf.  I suppose I could be wrong, but as yet haven't had any problems maintaining them...what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With 3.x using the LinqTemplates or in 2.2 using RepositoryRecord, you can write a repository base class and then add auditing in derived repository classes. [I demonstrated how to use a repository base class](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/how-i-use-subsonic-part-1/) on my blog (for 2.2).